# Map becomes black for half second when screen orientation changed

Tags: android, skmaps

I have an Android app that uses SKMaps version 3.0.2.
If I run it on a Samsung s6, when I change the screen orientation the map is destroyed and recreated (the map becomes black for about half second).
If I run it on a Nexus 6, when I change the screen orientation the map is not destroyed.

This is before rotation:

[image: before rotation]

This is shortly after rotation:

[image]

Does somebody know how to make the app not to be destroyed on the Samsung s6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this matter on the Skobbler demo application on Samsung Galaxy S6 and Samsung Galaxy A7 and the behavior is the same.

If `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` statement is used in the AndroidManifest.xml for the activity that contains the map then the activity that contains the map is **NOT** destroyed, neither the map.

If this statement is not used then the activity and the map are destroyed and then recreated immediately but no black screen appears.

Make sure you use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your manifest file for the activity that contains the map.